# App Crash when i want to get integer value and pass it to email intent

Tags: java, android

I am trying to pass integer values to emails from editText but app keeps crashing.

```
public class EditProductActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {`

 private EditText mQuantityEditText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit);

    // Initializing all the view variables associated to both product activity "modes".
    mNameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ProductNameEditText);
    mSupplierEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.SupplierEditView);
    mPriceEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PriceEditText);
    mQuantityEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.QuantityEditText);
    mProductImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ProductImageView);


    // Set onTouchListeners for all editviews/imageviews
    mNameEditText.setOnTouchListener(mTouchListener);
    mQuantityEditText.setOnTouchListener(mTouchListener);
    mSupplierEditText.setOnTouchListener(mTouchListener);
    mPriceEditText.setOnTouchListener(mTouchListener);
    mProductImageView.setOnTouchListener(mTouchListener);
  // If data is passed by intent, then display the current product in questions information\
    // Also known as "Edit mode"
    if (getIntent().getData() != null) {
        int i =Integer.parseInt(mQuantityEditText.getText().toString());
        Log.i("i===", String.valueOf(i));
        // Defining all the variables required for just the editing process
        mQuantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayQuantity);
        mSaleButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SaleButton);
        mIncrementButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.IncrementButton);
        mDecrementButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.DecrementButton);
        mOrderButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.OrderButton);
// Adding additional onTouchListeners to the newly tracked variables:
        mSaleButton.setOnTouchListener(mTouchListener);
        mIncrementButton.setOnTouchListener(mTouchListener);
        mDecrementButton.setOnTouchListener(mTouchListener);

        // Since we are in editmode, can hide the quantity editText and replace it with the
        // quantity controller view layout.
        mQuantityEditText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.QantityLayout).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        mCurrentProductUri = getIntent().getData();
        setTitle(getString(R.string.edit_product));

        // Handle the various quantity alteration options
        mSaleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                alterQuantity(-1);
            }
        });
        mIncrementButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                alterQuantity(1);
            }
        });
        mDecrementButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                alterQuantity(-1);
            }
        });
```

// below, I try to get the integer value from edit text, but the app crashes when I press the order button to send it to email.

```
        // Handle the order button request
        mOrderButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
```

// here I try again:

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
                int i =Integer.parseInt(mQuantityEditText.getText().toString());
                Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
                emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:" + mSupplierEditText.getText().toString()));
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Product Order");
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "I would like to order "+String.valueOf(i));
                try {
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email using..."));
                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                    Toast.makeText(EditProductActivity.this, "No email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

**LOGCAT ERROR**

> 06-16 05:02:29.790
>   4135-4135/com.example.mohammedragab.productinventoryapp
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                                Process: com.example.mohammedragab.productinventoryapp, PID: 4135
>                                                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.mohammedragab.productinventoryapp/com.example.mohammedragab.productinventoryapp.EditProductActivity}:
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
>                                                                                                    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
>                                                                                                    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
>                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                                    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
>                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                                    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
>                                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
>                                                                                                    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:533)
>                                                                                                    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:556)
>                                                                                                    at
>   com.example.mohammedragab.productinventoryapp.EditProductActivity.onCreate(EditProductActivity.java:104)
>                                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
>                                                                                                    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>                                                                                                    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
>                                                                                                    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
>                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                                    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
>                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
>                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
>                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Comment: add log for the same

Comment: @Dentor   how ?  i add log,i bu app crash

Comment: What does the exception say. If you are running this through Android Studio you should be able to see the log message.

Comment: Which `EditText` are you using to enter the value that gets parsed? You said EditText but didn't specify which?

Comment: @Dayan
this edittext  
mQuantityEditText

Comment: So you are definitely typing values into all the inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app is crashing because the inputField is an empty string, as shown in the error log:

`java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""`

This is because of your `onCreate()`- it's instantiating the `TextInput` field, which means it will be empty when you attempt to `getText()`. That explains why that `NumberFormatException` is raised.

`int i =Integer.parseInt(mQuantityEditText.getText().toString());`

**To fix it:**

Remove this line from the `onCreate()`, because that same line already exists in the `onClick()` event handler.

`int i =Integer.parseInt(mQuantityEditText.getText().toString());`

Here is the working code for your click handler:

```
mOrderButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
        String textFromInput = mQuantityEditText.getText().toString();
        String supplierText  = mSupplierEditText.getText().toString();
        if(!textFromInput.isEmpty() && !supplierText.isEmpty()){
            int i =Integer.parseInt(textFromInput);
            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
            emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:" + supplierText));
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Product Order");
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "I would like to order "+String.valueOf(i));
            try {
                 startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email using..."));
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(EditProductActivity.this, "No email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }else{
            //The textfield is empty, do something about it...
        }
     }
});
```

Comment: i remove it from onCreate but when i press order button app crash

Comment: Let me know what exception you get next, make sure your click handlers are correct. I noticed you had two! `mOrderButton.setOnClickListener` seems to be the correct one, but I'm not certain. The point is, you are trying to fetch a string when the textfield is actually empty, always check first before assuming the field is populated and attempting to parse.

Comment: i use  your code but nothing happen when i press mOrderButton
app not crash but nothing happen.

Comment: Well if you look at the code I provided nothing happens if your two text inputs are empty, hence the comment `The TextField is empty, do something about it...`. I recommend at this point, stepping through your code with the debugging tools provided by Android Studio/Eclipse or whatever you are using to see where the code leads. I did correct the problem though and explained what's causing it.